# Tabularray padding per cell

Tags: tabularray

In tabular, a cell can have a `\multicolumn{1}{@{\hspace{1em}}l}{Some text}` to set some left padding to that cell alone. In tabularray, the `\SetCell` command can be used to span columns but not to set some space to the left, like I mentioned.

Tabularray does allow to set the left and right space for that column, but that of course affects all cells in that column.

Is there a way to achieve this currently in tabularray?

It's a matter of `\SetCell` having something like the `colspec` key that supports the `@{}` syntax. In general it is a way to insert space for a single cell. Inserting space with `preto` wouldn't work, as it would be the same as setting an `\hspace` in the cell body and that only moves the first line.

Comment: You can use `\SetCell{preto=\hspace{1em}}` for left padding. But you would probably have to subtract the default `leftsep` from it to get the same effect as `@{\hspace{1em}}`

Comment: Hi @PietervanOostrum, this does indeed work but only for single line cells. If the cell is given a width then it only moves the first line. I guess I could treat the two cases separately and put the body of the cell inside a minipage if a width is given.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can change `\leftskip` for some cell:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabularray}
\begin{document}
\begin{tblr}{|m{2cm}|m{2cm}|m{3cm}|}
  Alpha & Beta & Gamma Gamma Gamma Gamma Gamma \\
  Alpha & Beta & \leftskip=1em Gamma Gamma Gamma Gamma Gamma \\
  Alpha & Beta & \leftskip=-3pt Gamma Gamma Gamma Gamma Gamma \\  
\end{tblr}
\end{document}
```

[image]